# How can I escape paths with spaces inside AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR

Tags: autotools, autoconf, m4

I need to include some paths in AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR which contain spaces. How should I escape them? For example, if I have "some file.in", how should I declare it in:

AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR[some file]

Comment: Correction: I mean AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([some file]).

Answer (score 0):

In autoconf 2.59 and earlier, you cannot have special characters in the path name of the unique file specified in AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR.  In autoconf 2.60 and later, this should work:

```
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([some file])
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. This is interpreted as a list of two files: 'some' and 'file'.

Comment: What version of autoconf?  Looking through the ChangeLog, it looks like this should work as of June 23, 2005, which I believe means it won't work with autoconf 2.59.

Answer (score 0):

`AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([some file])` works fine - make sure you really use the newer autotools, most distributions allow to install both autoconf-2.59 and autoconf-2.6x in parallel and have a wrapper around it.